# How to resolve Grails 2.x dependency conflict

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Today I cleaned .grails directory for a **Grails 2.1** project after almost 3 weeks of working on it without any issue. The error I am getting is

```
| Error Fatal error during compilation java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()Z
```

also on grails war I am getting:

```
        SERVER ERROR: Bad Gateway url=http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/asm/asm-parent/3.0/asm-parent-3.0.jar

    SERVER ERROR: Bad Gateway url=http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/asm/asm/3.0/asm-3.0-javadoc.jar

    SERVER ERROR: Bad Gateway url=http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/asm/asm-tree/3.0/asm-tree-3.0-sources.jar

    SERVER ERROR: Bad Gateway url=http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/asm/asm-tree/3.0/asm-tree-3.0-src.jar

    SERVER ERROR: Bad Gateway url=http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/asm/asm-tree/3.0/asm-tree-3.0-javadoc.jar

    SERVER ERROR: Bad Gateway url=http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/log4j/log4j/1.2.9/log4j-1.2.9-javadoc.jar

    SERVER ERROR: Bad Gateway url=http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/org/apache/ant/ant-parent/1.7.0/ant-parent-1.7.0.jar

    SERVER ERROR: Bad Gateway url=http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/org/apache/ant/ant/1.7.0/ant-1.7.0-javadoc.jar

    SERVER ERROR: Bad Gateway url=http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.7.0/ant-launcher-1.7.0-sources.jar

    SERVER ERROR: Bad Gateway url=http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.7.0/ant-launcher-1.7.0-src.jar

    SERVER ERROR: Bad Gateway url=http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.7.0/ant-launcher-1.7.0-javadoc.jar
```

The dependency report is showing a conflict

Module  Selected    Evicted

antlr by antlr  2.7.7   2.7.6

[here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0kgrli87HgRUjBzN1I0RGJTSTg/edit?pli=1)

Here is my BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" 
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
inherits("global") {   }
log "error" 
checksums true

repositories {
    inherits true 
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.oracle:ojdbc14:10.2.0.2'
}

plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.7.1"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
    compile (":twitter-bootstrap:2.0.2.25") { excludes 'svn' }
    compile ":audit-logging:0.5.4"
    compile ":quartz:0.4.2"
    compile (":joda-time:1.4")
    compile ":build-test-data:2.0.3"

    compile ":excel-import:1.0.0"


    runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    runtime ":cache-headers:1.1.5"
    runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    // compile ":cache:1.0.0"

    //provided ":code-coverage:1.2.5"
    //provided ":db-reverse-engineer:0.3"

    //provided ":grails-melody:1.13"
    //provided ":codenarc:0.17"
    //provided ":p6spy:0.5"
    //provided ":app-info:0.4.3"


    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    test(":spock:0.6") 
}
}
```

Any suggestion how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You might consider adding your BuildConfig.groovy. It's possible you're getting this error because a particular Maven repo is temporarily down and unable to pull the dependencies for a later version of SLF4J / Log4J.

Comment: @JohnnyWey thanks for the reply. It might have been some temporarily down time for one of the repositories, now I can download them just fine. However, the fatal error during compilation seems to be caused by the "provided" scope for the plugins. If I comment all the provided plugins, everything seems to be fine. I am not sure if this is a Grails bug or not but if I change the provided plugins to for example, runtime scope they work. Still its an issue but the workaround is to keep them as other scope and just remember not to include them in production